# Changing the title of a frame in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I have an application where I need to add text to the title of a frame depending on the user's interaction.

Is there a way to change the title of a frame in wxPython after it has been created?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try

```
frame.SetTitle('yourtitle')
```